# Reducing the size of osm zip for offline mapping

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid

I'm using MOBile Atlas Creator in order to create a map and then load it in my application for offline use with the the help of OSMdroid. My problem is that when I export the osmdroid zip it is way too big, it is 70MB making my apk pretty much 70MB which is unacceptable, is something I can do (ie removing redundant information) to lower the size of the zip?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often the solution is to put your zip file on an external public-facing server and have the app download the zip on first run. Something like your web site or on a cloud service like Amazon S3 would work well. The upside is that you could have the app periodically check the site for updated maps after the app has been deployed.

Comment: Additionally consider image sizes - jpg should be smaller (with a slight loss of quality) than an equivalent png.

Comment: Hi, thx for your answer. Is really the web a better solution than packaging it with the apk? also how can I configure the image sizes in Mobac??

Comment: Packaging it with the apk is the easiest solution but often unreasonable due to size as you are finding out. You can either reduce the size by using jpgs, or reducing the number of zoom levels (each zoom level you eliminate should reduce the size by about half) or you have to side-load it somehow like using the web. Those are the only solutions I have seen used.